# DSL line quality: SNR and impact on upload vs. download ratio

Tags: noise, adsl

I work mostly from home and last Sunday for some reason my DSL line rate dropped from around 8Mb/s to a 0.5Mb/s. I don't know much about the physics of DSL lines when it comes to line quality, so I'm curious if I'm being cheated by my ISP (I'm an expat in Italy and blatant cheating seems to be what companies here are about).

Current numbers from my TP-Link TD-W8970 are the following:

```
Line Status:         Connected
DSL Modulation Type: ADSL_2plus
Annex Type:          Annex A/L/M
Current Rate (Kbps)  796    672
Max Rate (Kbps)      829    2620
SNR Margin (dB)       10    28.2
Line Attenuation (dB) 23    38.4
Errors (Pkts)          0    0
```

The first set of numbers are for upload the second for download. As you can see the current line rate for upload is higher than the line rate for download. I'm curious if such a scenario can possibly be caused by line noise if there is no capping of the line rate on the DSLAM?

As I said the line rate had been constantly above 8Mb/s until it suddenly dropped last Sunday and has since stayed at current levels. My upload rate is still precisely identical to what it was before. In other words, if there is a strange sudden increase in noise, it has had zero impact on the upload rate.

Comment: I had the very similar experience on Sunday also.  Upload uses mid-frequency band whereas download uses high-frequency band. So my upload speed, margin etc were very stable/consistent, whereas download numbers were inconsistent and went really bad on Sunday.  A visit by telco techs 3 years ago found nothing, but this time I got a skilled tech who found & removed a 2000 ft bridge tap and also swapped my line to the CO with one that was 3000 ft shorter!  Voice quality has also improved; even the telco CSR commented on the buzz noise when I called Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

Your line seems to be artificially limited by the DSLAM. A SNR of 28 suggests that noise is minimal on your downstream and that there's enough leeway to support at least 6-8 Mbps without the SNR dropping below acceptable levels.